# Merge an Item Fulfillment with an advanced template and email it Netsuite 2.0

Tags: javascript, netsuite

So without the merge function below, this code sends an email on save, but I cannot for the life of me get email merge to work in Netsuite 2.0, so how do I merge an advanced pdf template with an item fulfillment and email it?

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/email','N/render', 'N/record', 'N/file'],
    function(email, record, file,render) {  
        function afterSubmit(context) {

        function templatemerge() {
         var myMergeResult = render.mergeEmail({
    templateId: 121,
    entity: {
        type: 'employee',
        id: 18040
        },
    recipient: {
        type: 'employee',
        id: 18040
        },
    supportCaseId: 'NULL',
    transactionId: 1176527,
    customRecord: 'NULL'
    });
        }
        templatemerge();

        function sendEmailWithAttachement() {
        var newId =  context.newRecord;
            var emailbody = 'attachment';
            var senderId = 18040;
            var recipientEmail = 'email@email.com';

            email.send({
               author: senderId,
                recipients: recipientEmail,
                subject: 'Item Fulfillments',
                body: emailbody
            });
        }
        sendEmailWithAttachement();
        }
        return {
            afterSubmit: afterSubmit
        };
    });
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Your syntax for merging an email template looks correct.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot find function mergeEmail in object [object Object].

Comment: You can also see my responses to your cross-post https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/forum/platform-areas/customization/suitescript-2-0-custom-code/411521-cant-get-template-email-merge-to-work-in-2-0?p=411526#post411526

Comment: Thank you, I have just responded to you there, this may be the first time I have ever gotten a response on the netsuite forums, kind of awesome.

Comment: erictgrubaugh if you want to post your answer here, I will go ahead and choose it as it was more complete than TonyH's answer.  Otherwise I will just give it to TonyH as he is on the right track.  Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rearranging the first function signature to `function(email, render, record, file)`

They are probably in the wrong order.